# Renaming multiple folders using perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, file-handling

I have text file file.txt which contains 100 words line by line.
I need to create 100 directories for those words in file.txt.
Each directory name should match each words in a line .
I need to create the code using perl for above query.

I tried as follows :

```
system("mkdir $_") for qw(tuber sp smeg  para);
```

Comment: Show the whole program you tried.

Comment: i tried this line i dont know to do it for 100 words of line

Comment: Try read the file with a while loop and call `mkdir` in the loop.

Comment: And if you have problems with the code (an error message) then come back to SO with a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't be using `system` to do basic file operations in Perl like mkdir.  Perl has built ins for this.  They're generally faster and have less caveats than calling an external executable.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

# This will make file operations throw exceptions so we don't
# have to write "or die" on everything.
use autodie;

open my $fh, "whatever-your-file-is";
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    mkdir $line;
}
```

If the file contains lines like `some/sub/directory` you'll want to use `mkpath` from [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path) instead of mkdir.